# Service httpd is failing to start - fcgid can't create shared memory

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, centos5, mod-fcgid

I'm not sure why, but when I try to start the httpd service, it will not start.

Server config:

```
OS: CentOS 5.10
PHP: 5.5.7
Apache: 2.2.3
```

Here's how I found out what was going on:

```
$ sudo service httpd start
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
$ sudo service httpd status
httpd dead but subsys locked
```

So I removed the subsys file for httpd, and I tried again, but it failed again.

My process for adding fcgid was as follows:

1. I built mod_fcgid from source, put it into the /etc/httpd/modules directory.
2. I appended `LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so` to the list of modules
3. I commented out `LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so` since I will not need it.
4. I created a wrapper script for php and placed it into /var/www/cgi-bin:
5. I created a handler for PHP that points to the wrapper.
6. Then I try to start the httpd service

The following is the error that I get in /var/log/httpd/error_log:

```
[Mon Dec 16 12:18:26 2013] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context user_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Mon Dec 16 12:18:26 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Dec 16 12:18:26 2013] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled
[Mon Dec 16 12:18:26 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Dec 16 12:18:26 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Dec 16 12:18:26 2013] [emerg] (17)File exists: mod_fcgid: Can't create shared memory for size 1200712 bytes
```

I see that it says "File exits", but I've search everywhere for any extra files with "fcgi" in the name, and I can't find anything.

I'm not sure if this is a permissions issue, or something with SELinux perhaps - or maybe suEXEC?

I would appreciate any guidance, since I'm not even sure where to start searching.

---

I tried again, and the error was slightly different this time:

```
[Mon Dec 16 12:50:23 2013] [emerg] (13)Permission denied: mod_fcgid: Can't create shared memory for size 1200712 bytes
```

I'm not sure which folder or file I need to change ownership of.

---

I set SELinux to `permissive` and it allowed the process to start without issue - but I do not want to leave SELinux as such.  I'll ask another question of how to allow Apache, fcgid, and PHP to work together under SELinux.

Answer (score 1):

just to test `SELinux` part, try disabling it and see if that's the cause of your issue:

```
[alexus@XXXXXXXXXX ~]$ getenforce 
Enforcing
[alexus@XXXXXXXXXX ~]$ sudo setenforce 0
[alexus@XXXXXXXXXX ~]$ getenforce 
Permissive
[alexus@XXXXXXXXXX ~]$
```

also, are you running doing it as chroot by any chance? I've had similar issue back to FreeBSD days, but that was related to jail/chroot.

Comment: I just tested that right as you were placing your answer - it does seem to be an issue SELinux.

Unfortunately, I have absolutely 0 knowledge of SELinux, so I'm not sure what to do at this point.  Any direction?

I'm using nearly a nearly default configuration, and I myself haven't specifically set anything to use chroot, so unless it's somehwere in the default configuration for RHEL's default Apache installation, I'm not.

Comment: if you "absolutely 0 knowledge of SELinux" i'd probably suggest you to keep it `Disabled` or `Pemissive` mode, at least until you're more comfortable w/ it.

Comment: I'm going to keep it on permissive until I discover how to correctly allow fcgi, php, and apache to work together while SELinux is enforcing its policy.